Google AutoML text entity extraction data split error without much details
I have a multi-label/two label dataset with more than 100 text items assigned to each label.
I used GCP console to label my training txt file. The uploaded .txt file contains around 5000 lines of texts and each label has 500 and 250 text items in them ,
Then i started Model training and failed now with the following message:

Due to an error, Vertex AI was unable to train model
"5000-rows-txt". Additional Details: Operation State: Failed with
errors Resource Name:
projects/67*/locations/us-central1/trainingPipelines/31* Error
Messages: There is insufficient validation data labeled 'stars*'  in
Dataset (72103511*,3456*) for automatic splitting.  Please manually
assign more items with the label into the validation data  item set,
or import more data.

Initially the text items in each label were below 100 items so increased the text items by adding more labels with more input text data, even after the console saying dataset is ready to start training i am getting this error, attached image of dataset labels 
